# How to enable subframes?

Tags: keyframes

A comment in this thread ( https://developer.blender.org/T73756 ) mentioned "enabling subframes".
How can I enable and work with subframes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the **Blender Documentation** that explains subframes
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/timeline.html

The following screenshot shows the menu with the tickbox to activate subframes.
**You can activate it from Timeline or Graph Editor.**

[image: Image of Playback Settings of the Timeline]

Once activated, your frame field changes from "**1**" to a "**1.0**".